# how can i convert async/await code to rxjs(observable)?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await, rxjs

there are many codes in my projects that using async/await. but i want to exhange all them to rxjs code.

But I'm not used to rxjs. Please tell me about the pattern or method of converting the async/await code to rxjs.
Or please recommend an example.

this is my original code (using async/await)

```
this.userHistory$ = new Subject(); 

async getUserStatue(userId, query){
  const userData = await this.UserApi.getUserInfo(userId, query);
  this.userHistory$.next(userData);
}
```

The code below is the code that I tried to convert using rxjs.
Please give me some advice on this code.

```
getUserStatue(userId, query){
  from(this.UserApi.getUserInfo(userId, query)).subscribe(
    userData => this.userHistory$.next(userData);
  );
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just `return from(this.UserApi.getUserInfo(userId, query));`?

Comment: thank you for comment. but the code I wrote works the same as the code using async/await, but the code you told me does not work. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly return observable from the method you define and subscribe to it. Subscribe inside method is not as reusable and producing side effects.

```
getUserStatue(userId, query){
   return  from(this.UserApi.getUserInfo(userId, query))
}
```

usage

```
this.getUserState('abc','some query').subscribe(response=>....do something with response)
```

Comment: thank you for comment. but the code I wrote works the same as the code using async/await, but the code you told me does not work. I don't know why. @Fan Cheung

Comment: Can you provide a stackbliz to demonstrate that. I think the code is quite straight forward? you didn't see any request made to the backend?

Answer (score 0):

The most direct translation is as follows:

```ts
this.userHistory$ = new Subject(); 

getUserStatue(userId, query){
  from(
    this.UserApi.getUserInfo(userId, query)
  ).subscribe(
    userData => this.userHistory$.next(userData)
  );
}
```

---

Of course, using a subject as an intermediary isn't nessesary. You can instead return an observable directly.

```ts
getUserStatue(userId, query){
  return from(this.UserApi.getUserInfo(userId, query));
}
```

Then instead of subscribing to `userHistory$`, you subscribe to the result of your function call `getUserStatue(...)`